# A vector that makes all norms grow

Tags: banach-spaces

Suppose that $E$ is a finite dimensional subspace of a Banach space $X$. A classical theorem (that I think is from Mazur) says that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a vector $x$ such that for all $y \in E$ we have $\|y\| \leq (1+\epsilon) \|y+\lambda x\|$.

This (to me at least) generalizes the notion of an orthonormal vector from Hilbert space, we can find a vector that is 'away' from the finite dimensional space and thus increases the norm.

My question is when can I remove the $\epsilon$ from this? Is there a 'nice' characterization of a space that means I can remove the dependence upon $\epsilon$? (Of particular interest to me are $\ell_p$ and reflexive spaces.)

---

The following is useful (and may be the way of thinking about the problem): this is related to the concept of Birkhoff orthogonality. Suppose that $E$ is a finite dimensional of a reflexive Banach space $X$. Then there is a vector $x$ such that for all $y \in E$ we have that $\|x\| \leq \|x+\lambda y\|$.

Indeed, by Hahn-Banach, let $f$ be any functional in $S_{X^*}$ that vanishes on $E$. Then, by James's characterization of reflexivity, $f$ attains its norm, so there is some $x$ for which $f(x) = 1$.

But then $\|x+\lambda y\| \geq f(x + \lambda y) = f(x) = \|x\|$.

So, in some sense, my question is asking the opposite of this.

Comment: You have answered your own question: Let $X_1$ be a subspace of $X$ that contains $E$ and has dimension  $1+$ dim $E $.